# Applying L'Hopital's rule to $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{x^2}.$$

If we apply L'Hopital rule, Then the procedure would go: $0/2x$, and then $0/2$ which is zero. What is wrong with this application L'Hopital rule, as it clearly seems wrong..

Comment: Do you have the correct form to apply that rule?

Comment: To apply l'H's rule you **must** have an indetermiante form: $\;\frac00\;,\;\;or\;\;\frac\infty\infty\;$

Comment: oh. That's why it went wrong!

Comment: What is your name is it really @L'hoptial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use the $0/0$ case of L'Hospital's rule, we require that both the numerator *and* the denominator tend to $0$ at the appropriate point. The numerator does not tend to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

L'Hopital's rule states that
if $$\lim_{x \to C} f(x) = 0$$
and $$\lim_{x \to C} g(x) = 0$$
then
$$\lim_{x \to C} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to C} \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

Another form of the rule is:

if $$\lim_{x \to C} f(x) = \infty$$
and $$\lim_{x \to C} g(x) = \infty$$
then
$$\lim_{x \to C} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to C} \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

In your problem $\lim_{x \to 0}2≠ 0 $ or $\infty$ so the rule doesn't apply

Comment: Your statement of L'Hopital's rule is incorrect. You need some additional hypotheses.